# python code to create VPC networks in Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

> I am looking for python code which will create VPC networks in Google
> cloud , please also include flow log field as well in code.

Comment: @MatthurDivya that is a big question,....maybe you can breaj down your task...search the internet for each task

Comment: I have tried to find it on internet, but unable to find any solution :(

Comment: Stackoverflow does not write code for you. This is the place to go when you have a problem with YOUR code and need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create the [network](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/networks/insert)
- Create the [subnet](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/subnetworks/insert)

In both cases, scroll to the bottom of the page to look for an example.